# why doesn't work TouchSwipe jQuery plugin in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I use from TouchSwipe jQuery plugin in my code for detect movement mouse and show pixel move when go to left or right.

I download TouchSwipe jQuery plugin from this address : [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin)
and use in my code...

this is my code :

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css/Newsfeed.css" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/Newsfeed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullpage">
            <div class="content-part selected"></div>
                <div class="content-part selected"></div>
                <div class="content-part selected"></div>
                <div class="content-part selected"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#fullpage .selected').swipe( {
                swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration)
                {
                    var str = "";
                    if (phase == "move")
                        str="You have moved " + distance +" px, If you leave the swipe object, the swipe will end";
                    if (phase == "end")
                        str="The swipe has ended"
                    $(this).text(str);
                },
                triggerOnTouchLeave:true,
                threshold:null
    });

});
```

but this jQuery code not working please help me.... XD

Answer (score 0):

your last js part ends with a ":" not a ";", maybe thats the problem?

EDIT:

I tried the code myself and it works fine, do your "fullpage" and "selected" divs have height and width?